# How to do pagination in tree-grid-directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I am using  following ‘tree-grid-directive’.

https://github.com/khan4019/tree-grid-directive

Is there any way to do client/server side pagination  in tree-grid-directive? Or  Is this support ng-grid for pagination?

Comment: have you figured out how?

Comment: me too having same question